# How to know which machines were skipped during DevOps Release using Azure Pipeline Agents for a Deployment Group

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm using Azure Pipeline Agents on Machines and have those Machines in a Deployment Group and I have a DevOps Release which does some things on each machine. If the Azure Pipeline Agent isn't running on a machine at release time, the release will skip over this machine (see below image). How can I know which machines were skipped?

[!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBX3g.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBX3g.png)

Comment: Do you get more details (logs) about the failed (skipped) if you click on the Failed area?  It should take you to the machine level logs.

Comment: it skipped because I stopped the agent on the machines, this is by design. I'm trying to write logic to handle how to respond to this. As such, I need to see if there is something in DevOps that will tell me which machines were skipped.

Comment: I guess from your question it wasn't clear on how you want to use the information about which one was skipped.  If you click on the detailed logs for the failures, you will see the details about the ones that were specifically skipped.  Does that not answer your question about "which ones were skipped?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I know which machines were skipped?

The easiest way to check is that you can manually check the detailed deployment log.

For example:

[image]

Then you could get the skipped agent name.

On the other hand, you could also use the Rest API : [Releases - Get Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). In the API response, you could check the `Job Status` and the `Agent name`.

Here is sample:

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=6.0
```

[image]